# Change a Label's style and template in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, label

I change a Label's style and template as below:

```
    <Label Content="Test">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#DDD" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="#EEE" Padding="4">
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />-->
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

in design time, this works and design view shows all thing good, (with each TextBlock or ContentPresenter); but when I run the project (or compile it), receive this error:

> Cannot find the static member
>   'ContentProperty' on the type
>   'Control'.

can anyone help me please? thanks a lot ):

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `TargetType="{x:Type Label}"` to the ControlTemplate (otherwise it won't "know" what properties are available).